# Raise event on system method run

Tags: c#, events

I have a console app that uses the `System.IO` namespace extensively, in specific `File.Delete()`, `File.Copy()` and `Directory.Delete()`.
What I would like to do is to raise an event when one of this methods run, something like this:

```
this.OnFileDelete += ...
//or
System.IO.File.OnFileCopy += ...
```

I know I can work around it with the `FileSystemWatcher` or by creating a helper method for each of the above methods but I'm looking for something more generic that will allow me to raise an event when a method not created by execute.

Comment: Is it possible to wrap the `File.Delete()`? So you could raise the event yourself.

Comment: It is possible (as I mentioned with the helper methods option), however I'm trying to figure out whether I can attach an event handler to a method not created by me

Comment: In short, no, you can't intercept method calls and trigger an event first. You could wrapper them, but it requires a different method call on all uses.